# How to find the number of possible permutations in a composition function

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

So I am given 2 maps. $$h = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$k=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4\\ 2&1&4&3 \end{pmatrix}$$ I am asked to construct a table in which I find all the elements possible so for example $h^2=(3,4,1,2)$  $h^3=(4,1,2,3)$   $h^4=1$ etc. How can I know that I have actually found every single composition possible in this table? I know $h^3=khk$ for example so it becomes repetitive after a certain amount of compositions. By the way the second row of the matrix represents the corresponding images to each of the elements 1,2,3 and 4.

I have found a total of $8$ elements so far and I want to know if there is any more that I am missing. Is there some sort of formula I can use to find how many I am suppose to have? I have the following: $1,hk,kh,h^2,h^3,kh^2,k,h$ So is the formula the number of compositions possible with $h$ (before it repeats) times the number of compositions possible with $k$ (before it repeats) $4 \cdot 2=8$

Comment: Well you are in $S_4$, how many ways are there to permutate $\{1,2,3,4\}$? Is that your question?

Comment: there are 24 ways to permute 1,2,3,4. But the fact that $k$ repeats after 2 compositions and $h$ repeats after 5 compositions changes the things a bit

Comment: do you mean $h^4=h$ ?

Comment: $h^4=1$ I'm sorry and $h^5=h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the group generated by $h$ and $k$. You noticed that $h^4=e$ and $k^2=e$. Also you noticed that $khk=h^3$ which can be written as a commutation rule: $hk=kh^3$. This means that every composition $g$ of $h$s and $k$s can be written as 
$$
  g = k^n h^m
$$
since every $k$ on the right of $h$ can be turned on the left by the commutation rule. Notice that $n\in \mathbb Z_2$ and $m\in \mathbb Z_4$ and this means that your group has at most 8 different elements.

You only have to prove that the are really different... First of all the elements:
$$
e, h, h^2, h^3
$$
are all different and also
$$
k, kh, k h^2, k h^3
$$
are all different. You only have to prove that each element on the first row is different from each element on the second row. To reduce the checks notice that $e,h^2,k,kh^2$ are even permutations while the others are odd. So everything reduces to check that $h^2\neq k$ which can be easily checked directly. From this follows that $e\neq kh^2$ and obviously one has $h^2\neq kh^2$ since $k\neq e$.

Comment: I am sorry but what theorem or lemma is this. I did not know that

Comment: I don't use any theorem, just some algebraic computation. What is not clear?

Comment: the commutation rule that you stated. Also isnt $kh^3=kh$?

Comment: You found $khk = h^3$. Multiply both sides of equation by $k$ on the right to obtain: $khkk = h^3 k$. But you know that $kk=1$ hence you obtain $kh = h^3 k$. About $kh^3 = kh$ you can multiply on the left by $k$ and obtain $h^3 = h$ which becomes $h^2=1$ which is false.

Comment: @ Emanuele Paolini I am working out the compositions of $kh$ and I dont seem to find a identity element for that particular composition. Also is it normal to have 2 of the same elements in 1 row?